# cyclic group - automorphism - $f_a(x) = x^a$

Tags: abstract-algebra, finite-groups

Question:

Let G be a cyclic group of order n. For each $a\in\Bbb{Z}$ define $f:G\to G ,f_a(x) = x^a$.

Prove that $f_a$ is an automorphism of G if and only if $a$ is prime to $n$.

I managed to show that if $a$ is prime to $n$ then $f_a$ is automorphism. When I try to prove the reverse, I need to proof that when $f_a$ is an automorphism, (i.e. the kernel is $e$), $a$ is prime to $n$. I managed to show that only when $m=kn$  will $g^{ma}=e=g^{pn}$ (m,p,k are integers). I felt the two $a$ and $n$ must be relatively prime. But I cannot prove it. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider $kerf$ Let $x\in kerf$ then $x^a=e$.Thus order of $x$ divides $a$.Also order of an element divides order of the group .order of $x$ divides $a$ and  $n$ both .But $gcd(a,n)=1$.Thus order of $x =1$ thus $x=e$.And in a finite group injectivity implies surjectivity and showing homomorphism is easy.Conversely let $G=<g>$ let $d=gcd(a,n)>1$.Then $a/d,n/d$ are integers.$f_a(g^{n/d})=g^{na/d}=e.g^{n/d}\in kerf_a$ since $n>n/d>1 g^{n/d}\neq e$ thus contradiction that $d>1$

Comment: That's the direction OP already knows.

Comment: To go the other direction, let $p$ divide $gcd(|G|,a)$, and show that $g^{|G|/p}$ is a nontrivial element of the kernel, where $g$ is a generator.

Comment: @Callus Your comment really helped me solved this problem. I found setting $p=gcd(|G|,a)$ and prove $g^{|G|/p}$ is a nontrivial element of kernel if $p\neq1$ would be suffice to prove this. Can u answer it desperately so I may select yours as the answer?

Comment: Cool. Glad it helped. Learnmore's answer includes the other direction now as well ( although note that $n/d$ could be $1$ if $n$ divides $a$ ). You can just accept this answer.